# Remove values but keep the key in python Dict

Tags: python-3.x

I have the followng dict in python:

```
d = {'ABC': ["DEF", "ASD"], 'DEF': ["AFS", "UAP"]}
```

Now I want to delete the value "DEF" but leave it as a Key.
so it will be:

```
d = {'ABC': [ "ASD"], 'DEF': ["AFS", "UAP"]}
```

Comment: `D['ABC'].remove('DEF')`? Changing the list won't change the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
for name, datalist in d.iteritems():  # Or items() in Python 3.x
    for datadict in datalist:
        for key, value in datadict.items():
            if value == "AAA":
                datadict[key] = ""
```

Does that work?

Comment: Doest this clear the values from that key? I need to keep the other values if present. Like this:  if the dict is d= {'ABC' : ['def', 'asd']} will be d = {'ABC' : []} instead of (when deleting 'def') d = {'ABC':['asd']}

Comment: It should.  that's why there are the empty quotes in 'datadict[key] = ""'  It should replace the key with nothing(hence the "") but the value should still exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'ABC': ["DEF", "ASD"], 'DEF': ["AFS", "UAP"]}
val_to_del = "DEF"

for key in d:

  if val_to_del in d[key]:
    d[key].remove(val_to_del)

print(d)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.